# MyFaces 2.0.2 + TinyMCE

Tags: jsf, tinymce, wysiwyg, myfaces

I was recently trying to integrate TinyMCE in my Myfaces application. I have downloaded and extracted TynyMCE in my webapp folder. I have written the following code:

```
<h:outputScript library="tiny_mce" name="tiny_mce.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript target="head">
                tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "textareas",
                theme : "advanced",
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fullscreen,undo,redo,cleanup,|,formatselect,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,|,forecolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "none",
                extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
                width : "100%",
                height : "260"
                 });
</h:outputScript>
<h:inputTextarea id="myTextArea" value="#{aboutBean.aboutInfo}"
                        rows="10" cols="50" style="width: 95%" />
```

As a result I see panel with instruments but there are no icons.[image: The result]

Any ideas how to fix it?

I just want to add that this code is part of ui:composition.

Comment: You can always integrate Primefaces with your project and get out of the box this editor http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [plugin parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aplugins) to your config.

This might look something like (make sure you include all the pluginnames here that you need):

```
plugins: "preview,save,searchreplace,inlinepopups,paste,wordcount,contextmenu",
```

Comment: well, didn't help me. I have a feeling this is a css problem?

Comment: try the following and tell me what happened: remove everything from theme_advanced_buttons1 except "undo" and set 'plugins: "undo"', only.

Comment: wierd, what happens if you use theme "simple" ?

Comment: I've try to put the tiny_mce folder in the webapp root as well as to the resources folder. still no result.

Comment: is your page accessible via internet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3924/discussion-between-dmitry-alexandrov-and-thariama)

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you load your tiny_mce.js file with a regular html tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

I solved my problem with **jsf2** and tinymce by replacing the new **jsf2** tag